# Faster R-CNN: How to avoid multiple detections in same area?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I use the Tensorflow object detection API to train the Pascal VOC dataset from scratch. I just had a look on the first results after 200k training steps and the results are okay, despite that I often have many detections of the same class in Overlapping regions. For example consider the following detections (ignore the wrong person detection in the first image):

[image: Multiple detection of the same motorcycle]
[image: Multiple detections of the same aeroplane]

Is there a general way to avoid such multiple detecions of the same object? I guess this is caused by overlapping Region proposals for which the Detection network predicts objects that fit the groundtruth data above the 0.7 IoU threshold, so maybe it would help to set this threshold a bit higher?

Comment: set high `nms_threshold`

Comment: have you run nms?

Comment: nms_score_trheshold is set to 0.0 because I want to see all detections my model makes,  but nms_iou_threshold is set to 0.7, which I thought of as a good value

Comment: @IshantMrinal why do we need to set it high? What is this parameter exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean literally from scratch, or did you use a fine_tune_checkpoint?

As others have suggested, you can increase the IOU threshold for NMS (decreasing it to something like .01 will effectively prevent a region from being detected if it overlaps with another).

Comment: To what value should it be increased?